# У меня неправильно работает код

Tags: javascript, html5

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Страничка</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
</head>

<body>
  <form name="myForm" action="" onsumbit="fun_form()" method="post">
    Введите ваш email: <input type="text" name="v_email">
    <br> Введите пароль: <input type="text" name="v_pas">
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Отправить">
  </form>
</body>
<script>
  function fun_form() { //функция должна проверять заполнение полей.
    var em_l = document.forms["myForm"]["v_email"].value;
    var pas_d = document.forms["myForm"]["v_pas"].value;
    if (em_l == "") { //email
      alert("Вы не ввели email.");
      return false;
    } else if (pas_d == "") { //password
      alert("Вы не ввели пароль.");
      return false;
    } else { //всё заполнено
      alert("Вы ввели всё правильно.");
      return true;
    }
  }
</script>
```

Происходит перезагрузка страницы и все, а проверки — нет

Ошибка в консоли:

> Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND

Comment: попробуй `onsumbit="return fun_form()"`

Comment: return не помогает.

Comment: тег скрипт то в боди должен лежать

Comment: onsumbit -> onsubmit

Comment: чтобы работало надо скрипт перед инициализацией формы сунуть, в head или в начало body

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/hhobn8em/

Comment: Спасибо, всё работает.

Comment: Напишите ,пожалуйста ,код который будет работать в гугле тоже, а не только здесь: https://jsfiddle.net/hhobn8em/

Comment: @саня каком гугле?

Comment: @Herrgott в том куда он устраивается работать

Comment: Гугл - это браузер. У тебя код после проверки выбрасывает: Cannot POST /index.html. Мой код в ответе этого не делает, а перезагружает страницу.

Comment: @саня ну правильно, поле `action` пустое, если на jsfiddle.net обратиться к несуществующему адресу, то будет ошибка. После отправки формы, должен идти запрос на API, где данные формы обрабатываются, после этого страница перезагрузится

Comment: @саня вот там зафикшен баг с постоянной отправкой при клике https://jsfiddle.net/hhobn8em/1/

Comment: @Herrgott Объясни, что ты добавил в код, а то отличий не найду. Работает и в гугле.

Comment: @саня есть же diffchecker.com `onsubmit="return fun_form (this)"`

Comment: @Herrgott А как это с твоим кодом связанно? Если там такого нет.

Comment: @саня я же новую ссылку дал. К старой `/1` добавь

Comment: @Herrgott  Да сравнил ты добавил return. Понятно return получается страницу перезагружает на начальную. Почему return так влияет на страницу? Объясни, пожалуйста.

Comment: твоя функция возращает `true/false`, `return fun_form ()` означает вернуть возвращенное функцией значение. onsubmit - тоже функция, если она возвращает true форма отправляется, false - нет. Если просто исполнение функции туда засовываешь, onsubmit по дефолту возвращает true. Так и работают валидаторы форм

Comment: @Herrgott  Спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Страничка</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
    </head>
    <body>
       <form onsubmit="return fun_form (this)"> 
        Введите ваш email:
        <input type="text" name="v_email"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        Введите пароль:
        <input type="text" name="v_password"> 
        <br>
        <br>
        <input type="submit" value="Отправить"> 
       </form> 
       <br>
       <br>
       <script>
       //не нужно писать перед form или head - не обязательно и так всё работает
            function fun_form (obj){
            var em_l = obj.v_email.value;
            var pas_d = obj.v_password.value; 

            if (em_l == "") { 
                alert ("Введите, пожалуйста, email"); return false;
            } else if (pas_d == "") { 
                alert ("Введите, пожалуйста, пароль"); return false;
            } else {
                alert("Вы ввели всё правильно.");
                return true;
            }
            }
       </script>
       <!--Нашёл ответ в интрнете-->
    </body>
</html>
```